# How do you use previous user input to determine key, value from (imported) module dictionary (you've created?)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, import, module

I am trying to use previous user input to determine, which key/value will be printed to screen from a dictionary created in and imported from a module.

The user input is their (the user's) birthday month. That month should be paired with the correlating month and "famous person" within the dictionary.

I don't know how to write the syntax - I get all sorts of error messages such as Value Error, 'function' attribute not defined when trying the .item() method, only 1 argument provided. And so on.

I've given it a go, but as aforementioned, could really do with some assistance to understand how to write and execute the program.

```
(module25)

def famousbirthdays (birthdayMonth):
    return {"January" : "Mozart", "February" : "Charles Darwin", "March" : "Albert Einstein", "April" : "Elizabeth II", "May" : "Linnaeus", "June" : "Josephine Baker", "July" : "Frida Kahlo", "August" : "Barak Obama", "September" : "Beyonce Knowles", "October" : "Gandhi", "November" : "Marie Curie", "December" : "Emily Dickenson"}
```

```
#import function from module

from module25 import famousbirthdays

#change variable name of previous user input, collected from multiply function (module25), extracting just the month

birthdayMonth = birthdayObject.strftime("%m")

#use items() method and search for birthdayMonth in dictionary

for k, v in famousbirthdays.items():
    if str(birthdayMonth) in famousbirthdays.items(birthdayMonth):
        print("Your birthday months is the same as", famousbirthdays.month(birthdayMonth).person(birthdayMonth))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me walk you through your code and comment on what may prevent it from working:

1. Your `famousbirthdays` implementation doesn't use the argument `birthday_month`, so you can omit it

```
def famousbirthdays():
    return {"January" : "Mozart", "February" : "Charles Darwin", ...}
```

2. In this row

```
for k, v in famousbirthdays.items():
```

`famousbirthdays` is considered to be a dictionary (`items()` is dictionary method), however `famousbirthdays` is a function, which returns a dictionary only if called. To call a function - do this `famousbirthdays()`. That way it will be indeed a dictionary.

3. At this stage on each step of iteration all the values you need are stored in `k` and `v`, `k` is key which is month, `v` is value which is a famous person's name. You can print them out and see:

```
for k, v in famousbirthdays().items():
    print(f"k: {k}, v: {v}")
```

Output:

```
k: January, v: Mozart
k: February, v: Charles Darwin
k: March, v: Albert Einstein
k: April, v: Elizabeth II
k: May, v: Linnaeus
k: June, v: Josephine Baker
k: July, v: Frida Kahlo
k: August, v: Barak Obama
k: September, v: Beyonce Knowles
k: October, v: Gandhi
k: November, v: Marie Curie
k: December, v: Emily Dickenson
```

So the complicated code after `if` can be changed to simple and correct:

```
for k, v in famousbirthdays().items():
    if str(birthdayMonth) == k:
        print("Your birthday months is the same as", v)
```

Now if I set `birthdayMonth = "March"` I will get `Your birthday months is the same as Albert Einstein`.

P.S. You can get the person's name even simpler

```
famousbirthdays()[str(birthdayMonth)]
```

or

```
def famousbirthdays(birthdayMonth):
    month_2_person = {"January" : "Mozart", "February" : "Charles Darwin"} # ...
    return month_2_person[birthdayMonth]


famousbirthdays(birthdayMonth)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can push almost all of your code right to your famous birthday function and just return the answer from there.

```
def famous_birthdays (birthday_month):
    
    birthday_dict = {"January" : "Mozart", "February" : "Charles Darwin", "March" : "Albert Einstein", "April" : "Elizabeth II", "May" : "Linnaeus", "June" : "Josephine Baker", "July" : "Frida Kahlo", "August" : "Barak Obama", "September" : "Beyonce Knowles", "October" : "Gandhi", "November" : "Marie Curie", "December" : "Emily Dickenson"}
    
    return birthday_dict.get(birthday_month, None)

birthday_month = "January"

famous_birthday = famous_birthdays(birthday_month)

print(f"Your birthday months is the same as {famous_birthday}")
```